# Can you pass parameters to DataTemplateSelector constructors in Xamarin.Forms app?

Tags: listview, xamarin, mobile, xamarin.forms

I am working on a Xamarin.Forms app with a ListView with 5 different templates. I'm trying to set the kind of template based on a "mode" (an int parameter) passed to the constructor. When I run the program, I get an error

> Missing default constructor for 'CampaignCellSelector'

My question is: Is it possible to pass parameters to DataTempalteSelectors? If not, what is the approach I should take? I have posted my code below.

```
public class CampaignCellSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{

    public DataTemplate CampaignTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate CrowdfundTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate PendingTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate NoCampaignTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate WelcomeTemplate { get; set; }

    public int status { get; set; }

    public CampaignCellSelector(int mode)
    {
        status = mode;
    }

    protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate(object item, BindableObject container)
    {


        if (status == 0)
        {

            return PendingTemplate;
        }
        else if (status == 1)
        {

            return NoCampaignTemplate;

        }
        else if (status == 2)
        {

            return WelcomeTemplate;
        }
        else
        {
         if (((Campaign)item).startDate == "")
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("point AA");
                return CampaignTemplate;
            }
            else
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("point BB");
                return CrowdfundTemplate;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to define a constructor which contain a parameters.You just need to set the value of **status** when you create the listview.

For Example

```
var listView = new ListView {
  ItemsSource = xxx,
  ItemTemplate = new CampaignCellSelector {
    CampaignTemplate = xxx,
    CrowdfundTemplate= xxx,
    PendingTemplate = xxx,
    NoCampaignTemplate = xxx,
    WelcomeTemplate = xxx,
    status = 1
    }
};
```